# How to expand ZIP archive using PowerShell (UTF-8 filenames)

Tags: windows, powershell

My zip archive has a single file:

```
Père-Noël.txt
```

The zip expands nicely with Windows File Explorer, 7-Zip or any other tool I've tried. But I cannot figure out how to do it from PowerShell. Obviously I've tried [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1) but it cannot handle the file name and garbles it into `PŠre-N”el.txt`. Note: The problem isn't specifically with this example, but indeed with any file name which uses characters outside of the ASCII-127 range. Or so it seems.

Any solution which uses PowerShell and which doesn't rely on an external tool - whose presence cannot be guaranteed - will be accepted. Windows 10 is the platform. I cannot do system-level changes and cannot rely on users of the script having any specific global setting on their system. It has to be a solution *within* the script.

Is there another way, besides `Expand-Archive` ? Or is there a setting in PowerShell which will magically do the trick?

#### Steps to reproduce:

On your Windows 10 host:

1. Create an empty file named `Père-Noël.txt`.
2. ZIP the file using Windows Explorer ("Compressed Folders" feature) into an ZIP archive of your choice, say `myarchive.zip`.
3. Delete the `Père-Noël.txt` file.
4. Now try to unpack the `myarchive.zip` using PowerShell. This operation should create the file `Père-Noël.txt` again.

#### Compressing using PowerShell Compress-Archive cmdlet

True, if the ZIP was originally created using `Compress-Archive` cmdlet then it actually works as intended when decompressing using `Expand-Archive`. So you can say that PowerShell is compatible with itself. It is just not compatible with Windows Explorer ZIPs.

Comment: @Matthew: That guy is on OSx and on Linux. I'm on Windows. The question is specifically about PowerShell.

Comment: It works better if you create the archive with powershell.

Comment: File names decoding is hidden inside `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry.DecodeEntryName(byte[] entryNameBytes)`. It uses `Encoding.GetEncoding(0)` by default. I don't see any way to override this using reflection. You can try select default system encoding which will match encoding in zip file. In my case I have used cyrillic file names, and correct encoding was CP866, but system encoding was different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely need to check the encoding `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings()` but the below works with your example `Père-Noël`

```
$zipfile = 'C:\test\Père-Noël.zip' #Contains Père-Noël.txt
$outpath = 'C:\test\out'
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(29001) #29001, x-Europa, Europa
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath, $enc)
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the example. It is the entries *within* the ZIP which use characters outside of the ASCII-127 range, not the name of the ZIP archive itself.

Comment: @peterh No misunderstanding, the zip contains Père-Noël.txt. 7-zip was used to create the test file and it defaulted to taking the name of the compressed item.

Comment: Okay, got it. It just confused me. I'll test it.

Comment: Bingo! this works for me. I've tested with an archive created with Windows Explorer ("Compressed Folder"), 7-Zip file manager and `Compress-Archive` cmdlet in Powershell. All of them expand correctly using this solution. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to the accepted answer but I like this answer better:

```
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$pwd/test.zip", "$pwd", [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding((Get-Culture).TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
```

[source](https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/88)

Answer (score 0):

Although we arrived in 2021 I stumbled upon the same problem.
Like the accepted answer my solution is based on the System.IO.Compression namespace.
The expand-archive command accepts pipeline-input and a -Force switch.
I had the same goals for my implementation - still in work and not thoroughly tested.

```
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(437)
Write-Output $encoding
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*.zip"  | Unzip -target "C:\unzipped" -f -encoding $encoding -v
```

[Find unzip function here](https://gist.github.com/heebinho/fd7f284a0dba12dcaae633ca9d590466)