# Java UTF-8 non ASCII chars not supported on Windows

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

I am working on a tool which produces a zip with some generated files. Some of my users using Windows 10 reported me that when I add a string into a file within a zip, non ascii chars are replaced by "?"
It is really strange because that works perfectly on linux (nixos). Do you have any idea?

```java
fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

...

```java
    public static void addToZip(String zipFilePath, final InputStream fis, final ZipOutputStream zos)
            throws IOException {
        final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(zipFilePath);
        zipEntry.setLastModifiedTime(FileTime.fromMillis(0L));
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0)
            zos.write(bytes, 0, length);

        zos.closeEntry();
        fis.close();
        if (!(Settings.PROTECTION.toBool()))
            return;
        zipEntry.setCrc(bytes.length);
        zipEntry.setSize(new BigInteger(bytes).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)).longValue());
    }
```

...

```java
  final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: `ZipOutputStream` with a character encoding? What package is that class in?

Comment: How are they checking this to see the "?"s ?

Comment: They most likely save their files windows-1252 encoded and you're reading utf_8 style.

Comment: @g00se I guess it is the one in Java, see [ZipOutputStream​(OutputStream out, Charset charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.OutputStream,java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: Doing `zipEntry.setCrc(bytes.length);` makes no sense. That is not what that field is for. That said, you need to provide a [mre] that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ah right. That's relatively new. Surprising. Anyway, as someone said above. Windows (at least in its standard console encoding) is often Windows-1252, which will not support certain glyphs which some of your UTF-8 coding might need

Comment: Did you check something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233853/how-to-expand-zip-archive-using-powershell-utf-8-filenames

Answer (score 0):

Since your description and your code is incomplete, I'm making a few assumptions:

- Some of the files in zip archive are text files (or similar such as CSV).
- The zip archives are created on a Linux system (or a single system under your control).
- The zip archives are the sent to your users and then used on different operating systems.

If so, the problem is not related to the zip archive. Instead, it's a general problem of text files. It would also occur if you just sent a single text file.

The cause of the problem is that text files do not contain any reliable information about the encoding. On your side, the text file is created using UTF-8 encoding. On the users side, different operating systems and different tools are used to view or process the text file. Some of these tools might make an effort to determine the encoding and guess it correctly. But if they just use the operating system's default encoding, users with Windows will use the incorrect encoding as Windows defaults to Windows-1252 and similar encodings.

The result of processing an UTF-8 encoded file with Windows-1252 encoding is that bytes that are not valid in Windows-1252 are shown as "?".

If your users view the text files with text editors, ask them to set the text editor to UTF-8. If the text files are processed with custom software, ask them to modify the software such that it explicitly uses UTF-8.

Comment: Some of the files in the generated zip archive are text files (json files actually). Given a content String, this is how I get the input stream: ``new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes()))``. The zip archive is created on the user operating system (the code I sent is the code which generates it). This zip archive is not correctly created on windows (encoding issues) but it works perfectly on linux. The generated file works on both OS if it was generated on linux but doesn't work at all if it was generated on windows.

Comment: `content.getBytes()` could be the problem as it uses the default encoding. Strangely enough, this contradicts what you show in the question. Please update your question such that we can understand what `content` is (a string?), how it's generated (it might already contain the damaged data) and how it is used to generate the zip archive.

Comment: I don't understand, where is the contradiction in my question, what should I edit?
I think ``content.getBytes()`` was the issue because ``content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`` seems to have fixed it. I asked a user on windows to try this custom version and it was working, I'll try to contact a few others.

Comment: The question shows `content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. So you have asked a question that already silently included the fix. What exactly did you expect us to do?

Comment: Ah I'm sorry. I didn't notice I did post this one. I'm actually using two different input streams.

Comment: I'm glad that despite all the confusion you seem to have found the fix.